# Applying group-specific function that returns a single series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, split-apply-combine

I'm trying to figure out an efficient split/apply/combine scheme for the following scenario. Consider the pandas dataframe `demoAll` defined below:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd


demoA = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2010,1,1), datetime.date(2010,1,2), datetime.date(2010,1,3)],
                     'ticker':['A', 'A', 'A'],
                     'x1':[10,20,30],
                     'close':[120, 133, 129]}).set_index('date', drop=True)
demoB = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2010,1,1), datetime.date(2010,1,2), datetime.date(2010,1,3)],
                     'ticker':['B', 'B', 'B'],
                     'x1':[18,11,45],
                     'close':[50, 49, 51]}).set_index('date', drop=True)
demoAll = pd.concat([demoA, demoB])
print(demoAll)
```

The result is:

```
           ticker  x1  close
date                        
2010-01-01      A  10    120
2010-01-02      A  20    133
2010-01-03      A  30    129
2010-01-01      B  18     50
2010-01-02      B  11     49
2010-01-03      B  45     51
```

I also have a dictionary mapping of tickers to model objects

```
ticker2model = {'A':model_A, 'B':model_B,...}
```

where each model has a `self.predict(df)` method that takes-in an entire dataframe and returns a series of the same length.

I now would like to create a new column, `demoAll['predictions']`, that corresponds to these predictions. What is the cleanest/most-efficient way of doing this? A few things to note:

1. `demoAll` was the concatenation of ticker-specific dataframes that were each indexed just by date. Thus the indices of `demoAll` are not unique. (However, the combination of date/ticker IS unique.)
2. My thinking has been to do something like the example below, but running into issues with indexing, data-type coercions, and slow run times. The real dataset is quite large (both rows and columns).

   ```
   demoAll['predictions'] = demoAll.groupby('ticker').apply(
                              lambda x: ticker2model[x.name].predict(x)
                            )
   ```

Comment: Instead of having a single groupby and running a function on it, you could refactor the predict function to work over multiple groupby's using pandas optimized DataFrame functions instead of a single function using apply.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your `predict` function: You are saying that it returns a series, and you assign the result of the groupby-and-apply operation as the new column. Can you provide some more details on the `predict` function or a minimal example for you demo data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood what you are passing through the model in order to predict but if I have understood correctly I would do the following:

1. pre-allocate the `predictions` columns of the `demoAll`
2. loop through the unique values of the ticker and filter `demoAll`
3. filter out the ticker row
4. predict the result using the filtered df
5. save the results in the correct locations in `demoAll['predictions']`

An Example using your code:

```
# get non 'ticker' columns
non_ticker_cols = [col for col in demoAll.columns if col is not 'ticker']
# get unique set of tickers 
tickers = demoAll.ticker.unique()
# create and prepopulate the predictions column
demoAll['predictions'] = 0

for ticker in tickers:
    # get boolean Series to filter the Dataframes by.
    filter_by_ticker = demoAll.ticker == ticker
    # filter, predict and allocate 
    demoAll.loc[filter_by_ticker, 'predictions'] = ticker2model[
        ticker].predict(
        demoAll.loc[filter_by_ticker,
                    non_ticker_cols]
    )
```

The output would look like:

```
         ticker x1  close   predictions
date                
2010-01-01  A   10  120 10.0
2010-01-02  A   20  133 10.0
2010-01-03  A   30  129 10.0
2010-01-01  B   18  50  100.0
2010-01-02  B   11  49  100.0
2010-01-03  B   45  51  100.0
```

**Comparison to using apply**

We could use apply per row but as you mentioned it would slow. I will compare the two to give an idea of the speedup.

**Setup**

I will use `DummyRegressor` from `sklearn` to allow me to call a `predict` method and create the dictionary you mention in your question.

```
model_a = DummyRegressor(strategy='mean')
model_b = DummyRegressor(strategy='median')

model_a.fit([[10,14]], y=np.array([10]))
model_b.fit([[200,200]], [100])
ticker2model = {'A':model_a, 'B':model_b}
```

**Defining both as functions**

```
def predict_by_ticker_filter(df, model_dict):
    # get non 'ticker' columns
    non_ticker_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col is not 'ticker']
    # get unique set of tickers 
    tickers = df.ticker.unique()
    # create and prepopulate the predictions column
    df['predictions'] = 0

    for ticker in tickers:
        # get boolean Series to filter the Dataframes by.
        filter_by_ticker = df.ticker==ticker
        # filter, predict and allocate 
        df.loc[filter_by_ticker,'predictions'] = model_dict[ticker].predict(
            df.loc[filter_by_ticker,
                   non_ticker_cols]
        )
    return df

def model_apply_by_row(df_row, model_dict):
    # includes some conversions to list to allow the predict method to run
    return model_dict[df_row['ticker']].predict([df_row[['x1','close']].tolist()])[0]
```

**Performance**
I use `timeit` on the function call to give the following results

**On your example `demoAll`:**

model_apply_by_row

```
%timeit demoAll.apply(model_apply_by_row,model_dict=ticker2model, axis=1)

3.78 ms ± 227 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

predict_by_ticker_filter

```
%timeit predict_by_ticker_filter(demoAll, ticker2model)

6.24 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Increasing the size of `demoAll` to `(606, 3)`**:

model_apply_by_row

```
%timeit demoAll.apply(model_apply_by_row,model_dict=ticker2model, axis=1)

320 ms ± 28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

predict_by_ticker_filter

```
%timeit predict_by_ticker_filter(demoAll, ticker2model)

6.1 ms ± 512 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Increasing the size of `demoAll` to `(6006, 3)`**:

model_apply_by_row

```
%timeit demoAll.apply(model_apply_by_row,model_dict=ticker2model, axis=1)

3.15 s ± 371 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

predict_by_ticker_filter

```
%timeit predict_by_ticker_filter(demoAll, ticker2model)

9.1 ms ± 767 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```